# Android moving search box to action bar on enter

Tags: android, android-animation

As part of the home screen in my android app, I have a search box(AutoCompleteTextView) in the center of the screen. Once the user enters something to search for inside that box, I want that search box to move up and become the action bar(or join the action bar) while the part below the action bar is now loading the recycler view. Basically something like this:

[image: screen 1]

to

[image: screen 2]

I haven't worked much with animations before so i wanted to know how this can be done.

Also how can I add a search icon to the right of a AutoCompleteTextView to act as the input button. That is when I tap on that search icon, the searching should begin.